# Azure POST request redirect using Azure services

Tags: azure, rest, web-deployment, azure-machine-learning-service

Hello I am trying to deploy my Azure Machine Learning pipeline with a REST endpoint. My problem is that I was able to generate an endpoint but has some sensitive information in it (ex: subscription id, resource group, etc). How can I generate a URL that forwards the request body to my Azure ML REST endpoint?

also, here is an approach I've done:

- Used Application Gateway Redirect (this approach didn't forward the request body. It instead turned my POST request into a GET request when it redirected to the correct URL.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is raised because of some of the default security headers dependent on REST API and web based. Need to set the [REST API CSP HEADER](https://content-security-policy.com/). Check the request and response headers in config file of the web application.